# How do you log to the Rails log file in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

Is there a way to log to the test.log file in Cucumber for Rails?

Using cucumber 1.3.15, cucumber-rails 1.4.1, and rails 4.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rails.logger` works just fine in step definitions, e.g.

```
Given /^I log on to the Internet$/ do
  Rails.logger.info "Logging on ..."
end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I read a similar solution that was missing the "Rails" bit.